# UWP Switching back to the main view Deactivate mainview functionallity

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am following the demo in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews I have it running perfect in my application, butn I am required to travel back an forward within views. I manage to make it work, but when I use ApplicationSwitcher.SwitchAsync to travel back to the Main page that is in charged of creating all the secondary pages, I cannot write anything on the textboxes until I minimize and maximize the app again. and I need to keep the secondary pages alive to travel back to them in the same state they where

Comment: Could you post some sample code so that we can replicate your problem?

Comment: I am currently testing the problem using the sample code on the link provided, the only difference is that inthe scenario1 and scenario3 xaml I added a textbox to verify that I can write on it when I came back to the view. I modify the secondaryViewPage.xaml.cs, I modify this function like this

Comment: private async void HideView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Switch to main and hide this view entirely from the user
            thisViewControl.StartViewInUse();

            await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(mainViewId,
                ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id,
                ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions.Default);
            //thisViewControl.StopViewInUse();
        }

Comment: an I use the scenraio3 xaml to test it because that is the behavior I need. The code runs and everything, thats why I gave the link to what Im using

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Please upload the all the changed XAML code snippet for the scenario 1. Did you change the root panel?